# log4j uses incorrect properties file in Netbeans

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, properties, log4j

I am using log4j in a desktop application.

Usually this works without a hitch. Recently however, Netbeans has stopped logging (while both Eclipse and the jar built by Netbeans itself log perfectly fine).

Using log4j's debug mode, I have traced the cause to log4j using the wrong properties file in Netbeans only. Instead of using the one supplied in the source folder, it uses the properties file inside of a dependency for some reason.

Again: This only happens in Netbeans. Does anyone know how I can point log4j to the correct file?
And why exactly would this happen?

EDIT: I am now manually feeding log4j the correct properties file, although I would still like to know the cause for Netbeans' odd priorities.

Answer (score 1):

The file `log4j.xml` has more [priority](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.java#103) than `log4j.properties`.

```
103      // if the user has not specified the log4j.configuration
104      // property, we search first for the file "log4j.xml" and then
105      // "log4j.properties"
```

So, you need to convert you current properties file to the XML style file. e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" 
                                     "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <!-- console -->
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="TRACE" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="conversionPattern"
        value="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!-- file -->
  <appender name="ROLLOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/tmp/output.log" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    <param name="threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="conversionPattern" 
           value="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!-- categories -->
  <category name="org.apache.commons">
    <priority value="OFF" />
  </category>
  <category name="org.hibernate">
    <priority value="OFF" />
  </category>

  <!-- root -->
  <root>
    <priority value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLOUT" />
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: This would fix the problem, but I still don'T understand why Netbeans gives the properties files in dependencies priority over the one in the source folder. PS: I worked around the issue for now by manually having log4j read the correct properties file, although your solution is more elegant.